Use keras-TCN for prediction with variable timesteps
So I am using a TCN to make a predictor model.
The input is (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim) and then the output should also be the same shape.
For that, I add a Dense layer at the end like this:
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_7 (InputLayer)        [(None, None, 1)]         0         
                                                                 
 tcn (TCN)                   (None, None, 64)          136256    
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, None, 1)           65        
                                                                 
 activation_3 (Activation)   (None, None, 1)           0         
                                                                 
=================================================================

However, I get the error:

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12081, 12080, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12081, 12080, 12077, 12084, 12083, 12082, 12076, 11998, 11875, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12077, 11956, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12082, 12077, 11231, 11090, 11082, 10966, 10965, 10946, 8446, 8441, 8439, 8429, 8425, 8416, 7034, 7032, 7032, 7030, 6941, 6935, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12083, 11915, 11230, 11090, 11082, 10967, 10941, 10940, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12083, 12083, 12082, 12082, 12080, 7105, 7105, 7104, 7104, 7103, 7103, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12082, 12081, 12078, 12008, 12008, 12008, 12007, 12005, 11992, 11964, 11964, 11963, 11963, 11963, 11963, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 10151, 10151, 6887, 5950, 5598, 5230, 5229, 5220, 3556
  y sizes: 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12081, 12080, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12081, 12080, 12077, 12084, 12083, 12082, 12076, 11998, 11875, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12077, 11956, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12082, 12077, 11231, 11090, 11082, 10966, 10965, 10946, 8446, 8441, 8439, 8429, 8425, 8416, 7034, 7032, 7032, 7030, 6941, 6935, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12083, 11915, 11230, 11090, 11082, 10967, 10941, 10940, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12083, 12083, 12083, 12083, 12082, 12082, 12080, 7105, 7105, 7104, 7104, 7103, 7103, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12082, 12081, 12078, 12008, 12008, 12008, 12007, 12005, 11992, 11964, 11964, 11963, 11963, 11963, 11963, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 12084, 10151, 10151, 6887, 5950, 5598, 5230, 5229, 5220, 3556
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Furthermore, if the second dimension is fixed for the train dataset like (515, 6644, 1) and the validation is (180, 6607, 1) it works. I also tried (1, 24531, 6) and (1, 5230, 6) (changing the input_dim obviously). So it does support a variable timestep but it has problems when the second dimensions changes for each train sample.
This error also occurs if I remove the Dense layer which is kind of a surprise for me. I thought the dimension restriction was imposed by the Dense layer, as TCN should be able to work with any timestep dimension as you can in theory compute the convolution at any shape, as will happen with a FCNN.
Where I am wrong and more importantly, how can I implement this TCN predictor?
